# Should I be importing com.myapp.R into my activities?

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, android-2.1-eclair

IntelliJ is moaning if I don't have the following imports in my activities :

`import com.jameselsey.apps.romandroid.R;`

I've got several other apps which don't require an explicit import of the R file, however this one will not compile if I remove it, I get the following error :

`\src\main\java\com\jameselsey\apps\romandroid\activity\RomanToArabicConverterActivity.java:[31,24] package R does not exist`

Understandably there are various other questions on SO on how to resolve this (none of which appear to work for me), but my question is : Does it really matter? Is there any reason why I should be wildly concerned here, or just go ahead and import it?

Tripled checked all my config xml, can't find anything that would prevent R being regenerated, mvn clean install still failing...

Comment: I had this. When the project is in the package `com.example.myapp`, but you want to use resources in a package `com.example.myapp.activity`, it seems you need to import `com.example.myapp.R`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go ahead and import it. I don't believe you should be concerned.

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't worry about it.
On a side note. If you want to regenerate R, you need to do a clean build after ensuring that there are no errors in the xmls.